# How to reuse static files across multiple APIRouters?

Tags: python, fastapi

If I've got the following static file: `static/example.png` and I mount my staticfiles like so:

```
app.mount('/static', StaticFiles(directory='static'), name='static')
```

I can now use that file in my HTML as `static/example.png`, so long as I only use views that are registered directly to my main app, for example:

```
@app.get('/home', response_type=HTMLResponse)
def home(request: Request):
    return '<img src="static/example.png" ...>'
```

And this works fine. However, if I create a new `APIRouter`, like so:

```
router = APIRouter(prefix='/dashboards')
app.include_router(router=router)
```

Now if I try to use `static/example.png` in a view that's registered to the new 'dashboards' router, for example like:

```
@router.get('/home', response_type=HTMLResponse)
def dashboards_home(request: Request):
    return '<img src="static/example.png" ...>'
```

I get the following error:

```
INFO: 127.0.0.1:52771 - "GET /dashboards/static/example.png HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

Basically, it seems that the `APIRouter` prefix gets prepended to every url inside my HTML, such as for href or src tag attributes. So instead of being treated it as a local static file, it gets treated as a web URL.

This means that I can't reuse my static files across `APIRouter`s without mounting a new `StaticFiles` instance against each one, making a copy of the static file under a new folder named after the router prefix, and then adding the corresponding router prefix inside my HTML (in the above example, I'd have to reference the file as `dashboards/static/example.png` and make the corresponding file copy).

This then means that I need a copy of each static file for every `APIRouter` that needs access to it. Even worse, I can't use jinja2 templates with inheritance features, because depending on where the parent template is being extended from, the static file it references would need different prefixes to be applied to it.

Is there any way I can get all views belonging to an `APIRouter` to NOT apply their router's prefix to any urls used inside the HTML they serve up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
You can reference the absolute path by prefixing `static` in your html with a `/`

Below is a fully working example of this:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

app.mount('/static', StaticFiles(directory='static'), name='static')

@app.get('/home', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def home(request: Request):
    return "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/test.css'><h1>hello from home</h1>"
# ---------------------------------------^ absolute path!

router = APIRouter(prefix='/myrouter')

@router.get('/route', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def route(request: Request):
    return "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/test.css'><h1>hello from home</h1>"
# ---------------------------------------^ absolute path!
app.include_router(router)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

**OLD ANSWER**

You can use relative pointers. The below is a full example, it should run as-is:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

app.mount('/static', StaticFiles(directory='static'), name='static')

@app.get('/home', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def home(request: Request):
    return "<link rel='stylesheet' href='static/test.css'><h1>hello from home</h1>"

router = APIRouter(prefix='/myrouter')

@router.get('/route', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def route(request: Request):
    return "<link rel='stylesheet' href='../static/test.css'><h1>hello from home</h1>"
# ---------------------------------------^ relative path!
app.include_router(router)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

This way, you can just have one `StaticFiles` declaration.

Comment: Huh, I can't quite understand why, but that works. That's cool. 

I hate to be difficult, but do you know any way to reuse static files across routers while keeping the references in your HTML the same?

I'm using jinja2's template extension feature for the header and footer of my website, and the basic skeleton that all views extend needs to be valid regardless of which view is extending it.

Comment: it works because `../` refers to the top-level folder. That's why `cd ..` on the command line moves you up a folder. However, it is even better to just use the absolute path, so all references remain the same. I have updated my answer (and retained the old answer at the bottom to match these comments).